# WebView Open External Links & target=blank Links in New Window like GMail App

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to Open External Links &

> target="blank"

Links in my WebView App in New Close-able Window like GMail App.

I tried to do the same as mentioned here:

[Android - Open target _blank links in WebView with external browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187714/android-open-target-blank-links-in-webview-with-external-browser)

&

[Handling External Links in android WebView like Gmail App does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779907/handling-external-links-in-android-webview-like-gmail-app-does)

But it is not working.

Please help me implement this feature in my App.

Here's the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
    package com.blogmaza;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static com.blogmaza.R.id.webView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    public SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String OSVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    int reqCode=0;
    public Uri imageUri;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    //  private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;

    public static class DetectConnection {
        public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

            ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            return (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(String.format("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android %s; BlogMaza v4 Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Mobile Safari/537.36", OSVersion));
        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.blogmaza.com");
        }
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new webclient());
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());

        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, android.os.Message resultMsg)
            {
                WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
                String data = result.getExtra();
                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(data));
                context.startActivity(browserIntent);
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Swipe to Refresh
        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                myWebView.reload(); // refreshes the WebView

                if (null != swipeLayout) {
                    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }

    public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        // For Android 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

            return true;

        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");

            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);


        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {

            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;

            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }

                Uri result = null;

                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                        result = null;

                    } else {

                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;

            }
        }

        return;
    }


    public class webclient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("play.google")){
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            }
            if(url.startsWith("whatsapp://")){
                Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
                String msg = uri.getQueryParameter("text");
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
                return true;
            }
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                view.reload();
                return true;
            }
            if ((url.contains("blogmaza.com"))) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            } else {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    private static final int TIME_DELAY = 2000;
    private static long back_pressed;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        }

        if (back_pressed + TIME_DELAY > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Also, I want to open the links of the websites from Google search app and browser directly into the app. As mentioned here:

[How to force open URL in WebView? Set App as Default for WebView URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495936/how-to-force-open-url-in-webview-set-app-as-default-for-webview-url)

Which is working fine. Only problem is, all the pages are opening the homepage in app.

Like if an user clicks on a link say `https://www.website.com/folder/page` from browser,
it opens `https://www.website.com/` in the app.

How do I fix this issue?

Here's the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blogmaza">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.blogmaza.com"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Here's the `activity_main.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.blogmaza.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
        </WebView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: I am fairly new in Android Development. Please post the solution with brief explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I have provided a simplified example of how to accomplish this with 2 Activities One that handles your initial URL load and Intercept of link click and other to load intercepted URL inside another view. First you need to implement shouldOverrideUrlLoading on your webview and return true for it. Then inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading you need to capture link clicked and pass url in bundle to your new View that you want to look like the GMAIl layout. Inside that view you can create a button that will return user to previous View.

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


            System.out.println("URLOFCLICK"+url);

            Intent intents=new Intent(cn,WebviewOpenerLikeGMAIL.class);
            intents.putExtra("URL",  url);
            startActivity(intents);



            return true;
        }
    });
```

Inside Your Look Alike GMAIL view

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.gmaillike);
    mWebView = findViewById(R.id.myGMAILwebview);
    Button closeVIEW = findViewById(R.id.button);
    closeVIEW.setOnClickListener(this);
    String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");
    mWebView.loadUrl(value);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    onBackPressed();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //this is only needed if you have specific things
    //that you want to do when the user presses the back button.
    /* your specific things...*/
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

[Here is the Full Code inside gist](https://gist.github.com/skryshtafovych/f37b9aafccb356282179284f2197c6a2)

Comment: Can you implement the codes in the codes I've posted above? I am new in Android development, its creating new errors when I try to add the new codes in the old one.

Comment: you need to update your question with what you tried.  What i have implemented is the base of what you should extend your sample on. I am not sure what your trying to accomplish with all your other classes.